# How to compile Fontawesome unique code with scss in css content

Tags: css, sass, font-awesome-5

I just wanted to add font awesome unique code with key-value pairs but when I am trying to do that it's changing

Ex.
content: ;

SCSS code

```
$socialMediaIcons: (facebook: '\f09a', twitter: '\f099', linkedin: '\f0e1');

@each $key,
$value in $socialMediaIcons {
    .#{$key} {

        &::before {
            font-family: fontAwesome;
            content: #{$value};
        }

    }
}
```

CSS compile code

```
.facebook::before {
  font-family: fontAwesome;
  content: ;
}

.twitter::before {
  font-family: fontAwesome;
  content: ;
}

.linkedin::before {
  font-family: fontAwesome;
  content: ;
}
```

Comment: The content doesn't show, only a box in place.

Answer (score 0):

I've solved the problem in my ways. Here is the solution:

1. At first, download the font-awesome toolkit from their website or using `npm` or `yarn`. I've downloaded the free version.
2. And then import the `fontawesome.scss` `brands.scss` at the top of my `scss` file. You may import `regular.scss` or `solid.scss` files if you want to show those type of icons.
3. SCSS Code:

```
@import "../../fontawesome-free-5.10.2-web/scss/fontawesome.scss";
@import "../../fontawesome-free-5.10.2-web/scss/brands.scss";

$socialMediaIcons: (facebook: $fa-var-facebook, twitter: $fa-var-twitter, linkedin: $fa-var-linkedin);

@each $key,
$value in $socialMediaIcons {
    .#{$key} {
        &:before {
            @extend %fa-icon;
            @extend .fab;

            content: fa-content(#{$value});
        }
    }
}
```

4. And don't forget to add font-awesome CSS file at the head of your `.html` file.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="fontawesome-free-5.10.2-web/css/all.min.css">
```